# Sorting a collect_set by count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I understand collect_set can have a random order.
Is there a different method of ordering a collect_set by count? I want to have an array of the most popular items for a single column based on a group by of a separate id column.
Would you have a collect_list and then run the count on that?

Comment: collect_set? that doesn't sound like python, if we'are talking about python the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module have some classes that might be of your interest such as [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) given that you want to count stuff and find the most popular of those

Comment: @Copperfield sorry should be pyspark not python

Comment: it's possible to get the count of every values in an array from collect_list using higher order functions. anyway, you could just provide a sample data of yours in order to get a clearer image of how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no method to order `collect_set` by count, as collect aggregate methods don't count items, information is not available to sort items.

So, since Spark 3.1 and greater, and given a `dataframe` with two columns `id` and `item`, you can:

1. perform [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.count.html) over a groupBy on columns `id` and `items`
2. collect `(count, item)` couples to an array with [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) and [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html). *Note: you can use `collect_set` here instead of `collect_list`, but it is useless as we are sure that each element of `(count, item)` is unique*
3. use [`sort_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html) to sort your array by descending count
4. map your array with [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) to drop `count`.

Which can be translated to code as follow:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

final_df = dataframe.groupBy('id', 'item').count() \
  .groupBy('id') \
  .agg(
    F.transform(
      F.sort_array(
        F.collect_list(F.struct("count", "item")),
        asc=False
      ),
      lambda x: x.getItem('item')
    ).alias('popular_items')
  )
```

*Note: if your spark version lower than 3.1 but greater than 1.6, you can replace `transform` with `withColumn` as follow:*

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

final_df = dataframe.groupBy('id', 'item').count() \
  .groupBy('id') \
  .agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct("count", "item")), asc=False).alias('popular_items')) \
  .withColumn("popular_items", F.col('popular_items.item'))
```

#### Example

With the following input dataframe:

```
+---+-----+
|id |item |
+---+-----+
|1  |item1|
|1  |item2|
|1  |item2|
|1  |item2|
|1  |item3|
|2  |item3|
|2  |item3|
|2  |item1|
|3  |item1|
|3  |item1|
+---+-----+
```

You get the following output:

```
+---+---------------------+
|id |popular_items        |
+---+---------------------+
|1  |[item2, item3, item1]|
|3  |[item1]              |
|2  |[item3, item1]       |
+---+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do popularity ranking analysis.you need to use collect_list to preserve duplicate values.

```
from collections import Counter
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


def elem_cnt(arr):
    return ['{}({})'.format(*i) for i in Counter(arr).most_common()]


spark.udf.register('elem_cnt_udf', elem_cnt)

data = [
    ('AC Milan', 'Ronaldo Luiz'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Paolo Maldini'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Kaká'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Ronaldo Luiz'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Andriy Shevchenko'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Van Basten'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Ronaldo Luiz'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Andriy Shevchenko'),
    ('AC Milan', 'Van Basten'),
    ('Milan', 'Ronaldo Luiz'),
    ('Milan', 'Paolo Maldini'),
    ('Milan', 'Ronaldo Luiz'),
    ('Milan', 'Van Basten')
]
schema = """
    id string,name string
"""
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp')
rank_sql = """
    select id,elem_cnt_udf(collect_list(name)) rank from tmp
    group by id
"""
rank_df = spark.sql(rank_sql)
rank_df.show(truncate=False)
```